# issue with Response.OutputStream.Write

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with this method, for some reason, I send request to my asp page, then read the `Response` stream and I get the content of my asp page along with the data I wrote into `Response.OutputStream.Write(info, 0, info.Length)`.

In my case, I write the string "1" as bytes, and the output on the client program is:

```
1<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="LauncherLogin.aspx" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZMraZTexYtyyQ9NaNN0YMvYIep5peaSEIrDBqxTff6rW" />

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want this HTML in the response I receive, how do I get rid of it?

Client Code (c# program):

```
public static string SendInformation(string values)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

    string postData = values;
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    // Prepare web request...
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverAddress + commmunicationForm);
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
    myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    string result;

    using (Stream stream = myRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    using (WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

ASP.aspx.cs Code (Server Side):

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Buffer = false;
    string errNum = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    byte[] info = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(errNum);
    Response.OutputStream.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Even if I do just this:

```
string errNum = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
byte[] info = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(errNum);
Response.OutputStream.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
Response.Flush();
```

I still get the html code :|

I did try `Response.Clear()` and other `.Clear()` methods with no success.

Comment: Show your actual C# code.

Comment: Are you positive you want ASCII encoding? Pretty much everything in the C# and .NET world is Unicode represented in UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to change the output too early in the page life cycle (you are trying to affect the total output at the event handling stage). You need to have your logic for altering content in the `Render` method. You can override the `Render` method, like this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // Your logic here
}
```

Read [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(VS.100).aspx) for more information on the page events and the order in which they occur.

Comment: o and thanks for the link, i do understand now why it happened !, can't upvote yet , still not enough rep xD

Answer (score 0):

You could try Response.Flush(). This should send what you wrote and get rid of what is sent afterwards.

Comment: Isn't it what i'm doing ?!